# OOP Javascript, get attribute of class not the event e

Tags: javascript, oop

In a event handler from my custom class, I want to use an attribute of my class in a private event method. Its more clearly with this simple example :

```js
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this._customAtt = "hello";
  }

  foo() {
    this._addListeners();
  }

  _addListeners() {
    $("input.two").click(this._anEvent);
  }

  _anEvent(e) {
    console.log(this._customAtt); // print 'undefined'
    console.log(self._customAtt); // print 'undefined'
  }
}

var myIClass = new myClass();

$('input.one').on("click", function() {
  myIClass.foo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' value='one' class='one'>
<input type='button' value='two' class='two'>
```

When I click on the button <kbd>one</kbd>, I add an handler to the button <kbd>two</kbd>. If I click on the button <kbd>two</kbd> the method `_anEvent` is called and from this method, I want use the private attribute class `_customAtt`. But, in the `_anEvent` method, `this` is the event e, not my class.

So, how can I can the attribute `_customAtt` from the method `_anEvent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because the context of `this` varies depending on how the function is called, not what the function was originally attached to.

One relatively easy way to do this is to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `_anEvent` to the instance of the class.

```
constructor() {
    this._customAtt = "hello";
    this._anEvent = this._anEvent.bind(this);
}
```

This will ensure that `this` is always the instance of `myClass` within the `_anEvent` function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I show a simple example but in my case, I create dynamically html content with some methods in my class, and finally, I bind to theses news generated elements the function '_anEvent'

Comment: @user2137454 `bind` will still work with anything created dynamically

Comment: I'll try that...and, from the _anEvent method, if I want use 'this' as the instance of my class and 'this' as the event catched by my handler, how can I do that ?

Comment: You'll need to change the way you handle the event so you can pass `this` (being the event) through to your handler. `$("input.two").click(this._anEvent);` would become `const self = this; $("input.two").click(() => { self._anEvent(this); });`